# Sorting array by sub object property of a custom object?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor, pubnub

I have an array of custom objects, `PNMessage objects`. The `PNMessage` Objects have a property which is another object named `PNDate`, the `PNDate` has a property called `date`, I would like to sort my array by the `PNDate`'s date property.

I think I could probably use sort descriptors but I don't know how to drill down to the property object PNDate and then sort by the PNDate date property.

here is a representation:

`myArray` - My array 
`PNMessage` - Custom objects in my array.
`PNDate` - Property (also an object) of main custom objects.
`date` - THIS IS THE PROPERTY THAT I WANT TO USE FOR SORTING MY ARRAY.

Is this possible?

This is what I tried but I know it's wrong, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to drill down to that property to sort the array:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date"
                                                    ascending:YES];
                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
                NSArray *sortedEventArray = [self.chatHistory
                                             sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using sort descriptors, you could use a comparator block.

```
NSArray *sortedEventArray =
[self.chatHistory sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(PNMessage *m1, PNMessage *m2) {
    return [m1.date compare:m2.date];
}];
```

Note that the `PNDate` class must have an instance method called `-[PNDate compare:]` that returns `NSComparisonResult` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, this may be what I'm looking for. Can I trouble you for an example of the compareTo method that I can add to the PNDate implementation file?

Comment: Does `PNDate` wrap an `NSDate` object? If so, it can simply call `-[NSDate compare:]`.

Comment: No, actually, PNDate inherits from NSObject.

Comment: It's difficult to come up with an example without knowing what data that class has available to it. There's an example of an `NSComparator` [in the Foundation Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: The NSDate compare method actually worked, I accepted your answer and I gave u an up vote for taking the extra time to help!